# sqlalchemy on raw sql. how can I access the underlying cursor.description?

Tags: dynamic, sqlalchemy

I am building and executing some SQL dynamically and want to output the data in text form.

To do so, I would prefer to present a neat little columnar output, typical of what you see in sql utilities.

```
col1              column2_has_a_really_long_name
_______________   ______________________________

has longer data   0.0
```

So, basically, **colwidth = max(len(colname), datasize))** will tell how much to pad each column (using a dynamically generated **%(colname1)-20.20s** type of template, where 20 would be col1's datasize approach).

The Python dbapi2 stores this kind of info, on the `https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#description`.

Is there a simple way to get at the cursor.description from a **sqlalchemy.engine.result.ResultMetaData** instance or something else accessible from an execute?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The underlying DBAPI cursor is available at `result.cursor`:

```
result = session.execute("SELECT * FROM foo")
print(result.cursor.description)
```

Comment: But I have to pick it up from the execute, won't be around on the ResultMetaData?  Fair enough, I can live with that.

Comment: @univerio could you please reference the documentation to `result.cursor.description`. Thanks.