# Retrieve columns from async oracle sql

Tags: python, fastapi

I am attempting to retrieve column names from my oracle sql query, but I am using FastAPI with an oracle db database. I know that `cx_oracle` or `oracledb` do not have asyncio features yet and its being worked on.

Therefore, how do I extract column names from the library `cx_Oracle_async`, which integrates asyncio with cx_oracle. Because, I checked the source code and no `description` argument is included.

For example:

```
class SQLFast:
    """SQL allows you to perform any type of SQL command in Python"""
    async def __aenter__(self):
        # Using cx_Oracle_async.create_pool to create an asynchronous connection pool
        self.pool = await cx_Oracle_async.create_pool(
            user=DB_USERNAME,
            password=DB_PASSWORD,
            dsn=f"{DB_HOST}:{DB_PORT}/{DB_SERVICE}",
        )
        self.connection = await self.pool.acquire()
        # Creating an asynchronous cursor
        self.cursor = await self.connection.cursor()
        return self

    async def __aexit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        await self.pool.release(self.connection)
    
    async def sql_query(self, query: str, return_type=pd.DataFrame):
        """Returns either a DataFrame or a list from a query"""
        try:
            await self.cursor.execute(query)
    
            if return_type == pd.DataFrame:
                result = await self.cursor.fetchall()
                if result:
                    # Fetch columns directly from the cursor description
                    columns = [desc[0] for desc in self.cursor.description]
                    if columns:
                        return pd.DataFrame(result, columns=columns)
                    else:
                        return pd.DataFrame(result)
                else:
                    return pd.DataFrame()  # Return an empty DataFrame for no result
            elif return_type == list:
                return result
    
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f"Error executing SQL query: {e}")
            raise
```

When I attempt to read a table from sql, I will get the following error:

> columns = [desc[0] for desc in self.cursor.description]
> AttributeError: 'AsyncCursorWrapper' object has no attribute 'description'

Comment: Perhaps you need to user `result.cursor.description`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39669115/sqlalchemy-on-raw-sql-how-can-i-access-the-underlying-cursor-description

Comment: @Malcolm thanks I have updated the script accordingly to include this, works now

Comment: @Emil11 prototype asyncio support in python-oracledb has been released, see https://github.com/oracle/python-oracledb/issues/258